# Need a way to make a button in Tkinter become DISABLED when nothing is highlighted in a Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

The aim of the code I am writing is for it to be able to remove items from an array and a corresponding listbox. I hope to be able to have the button that removes the items be DISABLED when no item is highlighted in the listbox (because otherwise it returns an error when you try to press the button and nothing has been selected, error is shown below.)

```
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\2Boys_stuff\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "H:/The Quiet Apocalypse/Tests/test_13.py", line 14, in remove
    LB = int(lb[0])
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

The code I am using is below:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox as box

global listbox
TF = True

inventorylist1 = [("Item1","1.0"),("Item2","0.25"),("Item3","0.25")]

def remove():
    global TF
    global listbox

    lb = listbox.curselection()
    LB = int(lb[0])


    del inventorylist1[LB]
    TF = False

    I(TF)

def IR():
    global windowir
    global listbox

    windowir = Tk()
    windowir.title( "IR" )
    windowir.resizable( 0, 0 )

    listframe = Frame( windowir )
    listbox = Listbox( listframe )

    for i in range(len(inventorylist1)):
        e = i+1
        listbox.insert(e, inventorylist1[i])

    Label_ir = Label( listframe, relief = "groove" )
    Label_ir.pack( side = TOP )


    btn_ir_1 = Button( listframe, text = "Remove", command = remove )
    btn_ir_1.pack(side = BOTTOM )

    listbox.pack(side = BOTTOM)
    listframe.pack(padx = 20, pady = 20)

    Label_ir.configure( text = "You are carrying: " )

    windowir.mainloop

def I(Tf):
    global windowir

    if Tf == True:
        windowi = Tk()
        windowi.title( "I" )
        windowi.resizable( 0, 0 )
        IR()
    else:
        windowir.destroy()
        IR()


I(TF)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `try and except` and show error as popup in except

```
def remove():
    global TF
    global listbox
    try:
       lb = listbox.curselection()
       LB = int(lb[0])


       del inventorylist1[LB]
       TF = False

       I(TF)
    except:
       popup = Tk()
       popup.wm_title("!")
       label = Label(popup, text=" ERROR")
       label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
       B1 = Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
       B1.pack()
       popup.mainloop()
```

Comment: How would you format the error message so that it works in python?

Comment: You can add a popup window in the except and ask the user to select an item before clicking the `remove` button

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help.

Comment: I updated the code, you can just replace the "ERROR" to display your message.